# Azure Resource Group name capitilisation

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have an interesting issue in Azure where somehow I've had some resources assign themselves to "Default-Web-NorthEurope" and some to "Default-Web-northeurope". (Note capitalisation)

Lets say I have Website1 and Website2. I'd like both of these to belong to the same App Service Plan. If I create a new one for "Website1" named "WebsitesServicePlan" The UI won't show me that plan when trying to change the plan for "Website2".

Has anyone else come across this issue and have any idea of a solution?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Azure Resource Group naming is not case sensitive. So I've no idea how you created two resource groups with the name **Default-Web-NorthEurope** and **Default-Web-northeurope** successfully. I suggest you double check the names in the portal.

Assume that the **Default-Web-NorthEurope** and **Default-Web-northeurope** are different groups and as you descriped **Website1** is in **Default-Web-NorthEurope**, **Website2** in **Default-Web-northeurope**, UI will definitely not show you the App Service Plan you created for "Websites1" when trying to change the plan for "Website2".  Because both apps and plans are contained in a resource group. Apps can be moved between plans as long as the plans are in the same resource group and geographical region. In other words, when you want to change plans for app, the plans must be in the same resource group and geographical region.

Check [azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/) for details.

Comment: In the Resource Groups panel it lists only 1. But when viewing the different web applications it has 2 different names. Then subsequently the issue with app service plans.

Comment: You created two resource groups respectively or you just created one?

Comment: When creating a new App service, it's allowed to type a new resource group name manually even though it's already existed. I guess that's why there are **Default-Web-NorthEurope** and **Default-Web-northeurope** at the same time. But when you click the one in Resource Groups panel,**Website1** and **Website2** should both in the Resources list. Nevertheless, they are still deemed to belong to diferent resource groups in Azure and hence the issue happens. I think it's a bug/issue which needs Microsoft Azure to fix.

Comment: The resource groups were created with default values when creating new web apps. I didn't notice they had different names until recently. But they were created a while ago but separately. So it's possible the MS changed their naming in that gap.

Comment: Seems we both neglect something. The original plan for "Website2", which should be in the same resource group and geographical region with "WebsitesServicePlan" , otherwise, you can't change it to "WebsitesServicePlan".

Comment: we are misled by **Default-Web-NorthEurope** and **Default-Web-northeurope** from the beginning. They are one as you see in the RG panel. The app and its plan are not required to be in the same RG, but the original plan and plan to be changed are. Get back to me after you check.

Comment: I just went onto the Azure portal to take some screenshots to better explain the situation... My websites now have the same naming for their resource groups and I can assign them both to the same service plan...  Suspicious? Yes. Undocumented bug and silent hotfix? Possible. Grateful? Very.